# How to add parameters at --function

Tags: linux, sorting

I want to sort alphabetical the ps list.

After I type my command I have `--sort=PPID` but I want to print reversed sort, that mean `sort -r` but I can't use `[command] --sort -r PPID` or `[command] --sort --r PPID`.

Comment: Have you tried reading [the `ps` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)? Its documentation of the `--sort` argument should give some hints.

Comment: My question is about adding parameters to a --function

Comment: That isn't really clear, it seems like you want to reverse the sorting of the `ps` command, which you do with e.g. `ps --sort=-ppid`. Nothing more needed.

Comment: As for "adding parameters to a --function", in almost all cases you can't. First of all, few of the commands you use are actually functions. Most of them are compiled programs. Some are scripts (Python, Perl, or Bash) where you can edit the source, but you shouldn't do that, not before you learn a little more about the commands and how arguments are handled (and of course about the languages used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--sort` is sorting on key, which is the `n`th column on your result.

The standard output seems to be : `PID`, `TTY`, ...

So:
If you want to sort on `PID`, you do : `ps --sort 1`,
If you want to sort on `TTY`, you do : `ps --sort 2`,
...